# Xorg freezing during high system load

Tags: linux, nvidia, gentoo

I have problem with my Gentoo system. Xorg freezes and sound loops when system is under high load. I use Xorg session. Can this problem be caused by the proprietary NVIDIA drivers? If I get rid of proprietary NVIDIA drivers and if I switch to Intel GPU, will this problem still occur?

Comment: When exactly does this happen? What precedes it? What do you mean by high load? What is your hardware? Did you check RAM and swap usage? It is probably not related to proprietary drivers.

Comment: This problem happens when RAM is full. By high load I mean high CPU and RAM usage. Usually nothing precedes it, sometimes maybe cursor jumps on the screen. My hardware is MSI GP63 Leopard 8RE.

Comment: Do you use swap partition/file and do you have it configured correctly? When you get out of the free RAM and there is no swap, a system freeze is expected.

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Swap